# Match Entire String

Tags: c#, regex, string

This is an example of something that I need to accomplish as part of a larger program. The example contains two listViews. listViewInput contains three items of text: "banana", "banana tree" and "banana peel".

I need to iterate through the listView items and find the item whose text is *entirely* contained within the string textToCompare. textToCompare will always have extra text on one or both sides of the actual string that I am looking for(not going to be an == thing).

The problem with this comparison is that the If statement is going to return true for listView item "banana" as well as "banana tree". This seems simple enough, but I have tried everything I can think of and had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
string textToCompare = "word banana tree more words";

for (int i = 0; i < listViewInput.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(textToCompare, listViewInput.Items[i].Text))
    {
         listViewOutput.Items.Add(listViewInput.Items[i].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? As a matter of fact "banana" and "banana tree" are both "_entirely_ contained" in the textToCompare.

Comment: start compare from the longest list items. then you can achieve your result

Comment: @ EricSchaefer That is true that both are entirely contained; I will try to explain more clearly. My expected outcome is to "get/find" a listview item by having its text contained in textToCompare. Ex: If textToCompare contains "banana tree", I want only the listview item whose text == "banana tree". If textToCompare contains only "banana", I want only the listview item whose text == "banana" , etc. The listview items are known and constant values, but the string could contain other words before and after the text I'm looking for.

Comment: so, you want the longest match here, like @Haji suggested? or do you want both?

Comment: @Haji Due to the context of this code, I am not able to use the listview item text as input to the IsMatch.

Comment: @Purrfection Yes, if "banana tree" is input, I do not want the If to be true for item "banana".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's your revised answer, returning the largest match:

```
// This is the equivalent to your `listViewInput.Item`
string[] words = new string[] { "banana", "banana tree" , "banana peel"};

string textToCompare = "word banana tree more words";

string longest_match = 
    (from word in words.OrderByDescending(w => w.Length)
     where textToCompare.Contains(word)
     select word).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will end with the `longest_match` holding "banana tree".

Not sure why you need your regex ... Use Contains, and change my words array to your items source.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, since the string happens to contain "banana tree", not just "banana", I do not want the result to include "banana".

Comment: you can then just use the `silly_longest` (since it's a silly way of getting it). You could sort your equivalent to `words` by length, and then once you hit one that returns `true` for the `contains`, break the loop and you'll have the longest result.

Comment: what if he had "words" in his `listViewINput`, then it would be excluded because it's not long enough but it isn't a match for "banana tree"

Comment: @Noctis This works perfectly! I just had to add the listView items to a ListViewItem[], then convert that to a string[]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't do c# but algorithmically you'll need two passes. The second pass will have a logarithmic reduction in cost though.

I think you'll have to:

1. sort the `listViewInput` by length of entries
2. then loop the list again comparing to `textToCompare`. You can use regex but make sure it uses word boundaries.
3. Each time you hit a match you remove that item from the `TextToCompare` for the next iteration.   e..g remove "banana tree".  somewhere later in the sorted list "banana" will fail to match

on #2: your input items stay as is, but the regex is going to be dynamic portion of this.  like i said I don't do c# so please edit syntax someone, especially the IsMatch method :

```
string textToCompare = "word banana tree more words";

for (int i = 0; i < listViewInput.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string regex = `\b'+listViewInput.Items[i].Text[i]+'\b`  // e.g. `\bbanana\b`
    if (Regex.IsMatch(textToCompare,regex ))
    {
        listViewOutput.Items.Add(listViewInput.Items[i].Text);
    }
}
```